# How to set multiple field in Firestore document at once in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write two arrays of a custom object to Firestore document.
When I execute the program it only write the last one from the array.

The custom class is codable and encodable.

This is the function that execute the write function to Firestore:

```
func setShiftConstraints<ShiftConst: Codable>(employeeId: String, for encodeObject: ShiftConst, completion: @escaping (Bool)->()){

    do{
        let json = try encodeObject.toJson(excluding: [], photoString: nil)
        let date = Date().toFormat(DateFormats.format3.rawValue)
        self.db.batch().setData([date : json], forDocument: self.reference(to: .shifts).document(employeeId), merge: false).commit()
        print("Shift uploaded!")
        completion(true)
    }catch let err{
        print(err.localizedDescription)
        completion(false)
    }

}
```

And this is the function that get called when the user is submitting his arguments.

```
func sendShiftsDataToCloud(){

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    var returned = true

    shiftConsts[0].shiftType = ShiftType(rawValue: self.shift1SegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex)!

    shiftConsts[1].shiftType = ShiftType(rawValue: self.shift2SegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex)!

    for shift in self.shiftConsts{

        group.enter()

        shift.date = Day().convertDateFormat(from: .format1, to: .format9, date: shift.date)

        self.service.setShiftConstraints(employeeId: self.service.currentUid!, for: shift) { (finish) in

            if !finish{
                returned = false
            }

        }
        group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        if returned{
            print("finish")
            Alert.showAlert(title: "Success!", text: "", type: .success)
        }else{
            print("error")
            Alert.showAlert(title: "Error!", text: "Please try again.", type: .error)
        }
    }

}
```

the result is one array instead of two:

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting this `.setData([date : json]` to do? Looking at your Firestore it did what it was supposed to do, write date and the associated data.

Comment: I'm expecting to have two fields (because this function called twice) each one with the date and the parameters inside. the results I'm getting is only one as you can see.

Comment: Understood. I think regardless of how many times it's called, if you pass it the same data as the documentId over and over it will just keep overwriting the node. In other words, it seems that it's being passed `self.service.currentUid!` every time so the document just get's overwritten with only the last set of data from the array remaining.

Comment: I thought that this might be the case, one way I found it would work is to set documentID() so it will generate a number.
The thing is that I want to have this array at the same document just different fields.
For example : shifts > self.service.currentUid > the array with his two fields.

Comment: I kinda understand the intent but I am not sure of the specifics of the end result. First off, that's not an array - which is fine because arrays should generally be avoided in NoSQL databases and I don't think it's the right type for this use case anyway. Can you update the question with a clear example of your intended result? I think you're close but need to see it in writing.